# Sqlite atomically read and update a counter?

Tags: sqlite, atomic

I am trying to implement a simple counter using SQLite provided with Python. I am using CGI to write simple dynamic web pages. It's the only simple way I can think of to implement a counter. The problem is I need to first read the counter value and then update it. But ideally, every user should read a unique value, and it's possible for two users to read the same counter value if they read simultaneously. Is there a simple way to make the read/write operation atomic? I unfamiliar with SQL so please give specific statements to do so. Thanks in advance.

I use a table with one column and one row to store the counter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try this flow of SQL statements:

```
BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION;
// update counter here
// retrieve new value for user
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

While you perform updates in trisection, changes can be seen only with connection on which they was performed. In this case we used **EXCLUSIVE** transactions, which locks database for other clients till it will commit transaction.

Comment: Thanks. Do I use multiple Connection.execute for this?

Comment: I'm not sure how other API for SQLite works, most of the API cal's can't perform few commands in one statement.

Comment: There is a function called executescript. But I am not sure how the result is retrieved because there is no documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

The complete code:

```
BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION;
UPDATE table_name SET counter = COALESCE(counter, 0) + 1;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score -2):

You should better not use the EXCLUSIVE keyword in the transaction to make it more efficient. The first select automatically creates a shared lock and the update statement will then turn it into an exclusive. It is only necessary that the SELECT and the UPDATE are both inside an explicit set transaction.

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
// read counter value
// update counter value
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: The current [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) **explicitly** contradicts this in the section titled "Read transactions versus write transactions". In particular this last paragraph addresses this very scenario. Using your scheme it's possible for X and Y to both read the same counter C value concurrently: X goes first and replaces the counter with C+1, then commits the transaction; the Y goes and replaces the C+1 that X put there with C+1 again, then commits the transaction. You have to use the EXCLUSIVE keyword.