# Peewee mid-air collision detection with SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I have a couple models that I want to update at the same time. First I get their data from the db with a simple:

```
s = Store.get(Store.id == store_id)
new_book = Book.get(Book.id == data[book_id'])
old_book = Book.get(Book.id == s.books.id)
```

The actual schema is irrelevant here. Then I do some updates to these models and at the end I save all three of them with:

```
s.save()
new_book.save()
old_book.save()
```

The function that handles these operations uses the `@db.atomic()` decorator so the writes are bunched into a single transaction. The problem is that what if, between the point where I `get()` the data from the DB and the point where I save the modified data, another process changed something with these models in the DB already. Is there a way to execute those writes (`.save()` operations) only if the underlying DB rows have not been changed? I could read their `last_changed` value but again, is there a way to do this *and* update at the same time? And if data has been changed, simply throw an exception?

Comment: I would modify the `UPDATE` SQL with a condition that ensures that the `last_changed` is the same as when you originally read the records.

Comment: @joeb Do you have an example of what that might look like in Peewee, especially when updating two different tables?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Peewee but check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/27528623/174652 and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079540/sqlite-atomically-read-and-update-a-counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a solution for this in the official docs called [Optimistic Locking](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/hacks.html#optimistic-locking).